# talk with excel objects from outside of excel

Tags: excel, vbscript

I want to get information from an Excel Workbook through VBscript outside of Excel.  I can get to worksheet data. Now I want to get information from UserForms and Objects on the UserForms.  I tried the code below and it gives an error on the msgbox line.

Thanks,
Kevin

```
Dim oExcel
Dim oWb
Dim oSheet

Set oExcel =  CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set oWb = oExcel.WorkBooks.Open("C:\KAA\KAA.XLSM") 

msgbox oWb.UserForm1.height

oWb.Close
Set oExcel = Nothing
Set oWb = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

To access programmatic objects you need to access the `VBProject` of the workbook.

```
MsgBox oWb.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Name
MsgBox oWb.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Designer.InsideHeight
```

But prior to that you need (on your own responsibility) to set the security to *Trust Access to the VBA project object model*

```
File -> Options -> Trust Center -> Trust Center Settings -> Trust Access to the VBA project object model.
```